# Modifying non const attribute in const function

Tags: c++

So I have a class with the following function :
`void AddNoiseToAim(Vector2D& position) const` which is essentialy a utility function.

To correctly compute the noise I use a complexe object which require kind of a heavy initialisation so to avoid doing it at every call of the function, I decided to put the object as a non const attribute of the class so the initialisation is performed once at the instantiation and then used multiple time by the function.

The problem is that `AddNoiseToAim` is const and the attribute is not so I can't use it in the function, BUT the attribute is only used for this specific purpose so the only thing that retain me from putting it in the scope of the function is the initialisation of the object.

I thought of 3 solutions for now, the first one is to remove the const modifier of the AddNoiseToAim but I don't want to do that, since by nature this function doesn't modify the instance of the class. Second solution would be to pass the attribute as a reference to the function like it's done for the parameter position, but even that feel kind of weird, since it's like making a detour. Finally the solution I've gone with for now but which would give me memory issues is doing something like that :

```
void Raven_WeaponSystem::AddNoiseToAim(Vector2D& AimingPos) const
{
    static FuzzyModule* fuzzyModule = InitializeFuzzyModule();
    /* omitted */
}
```

FuzzyModule is not an attribute of the class anymore.

In my case Raven_WeaponSystem has the same life span as the application, so I don't really care about the lost memory but it really doesn't feel good.

To sum up ! I would like the function to initialize an object in its scope only once at the first call of the function OR I would like the object to be initialize outside of the function and used in the constant function (in which case my second solution should suffice).

Thanks for your time ! Cheers.

Comment: Still not really clear what you want here? A Singleton? Can you give more context?

Comment: The answer below hit the right spot thanks :) I wanted to be able to modify an attribute that didn't impact the class inside a const function and the mutable keyword seems to be exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't initialize `fuzzyModule` in the constructor, declare it `mutable` in the class (which will allow you to modify its value in a `const` function).

```
mutable FuzzyModule *fuzzyModule;
```